# Tachometer On My Car Is Doing The Opposite At Warm up

Tags: repair, gauges, motors

The car is Ford Focus 2002 model. Ztec engine. 1.6V

I'll go straight to the point. The problem started when I got my car engine washed (with water). I changed the coil, and plugs. It started running fine until after few days later, I had to try several times before it could start. An auto electrician checked it and adjusted the IDLE SPEED. It started in one try in his shop but the problem persisted when I got home. The following morning, I noticed the TACHOMETER did the opposite - before the guy adjusted the idle speed,  the normal behaviour of tachometer was to start coming down slowly from about 1000rpm to about 650rpm. But now, the tachometer starts from about 650rpm and goes up slowly till almost 1000rpm during warm up in the morning.

Forgive me for the poor explanation. I took it back to the guy, he changed the fuel pump (used one). The car has been responding to one start or two since then but the tachometer continues the abnormal behaviour (my observation). To cut the story short, I changed the fuel pump to a new one today when I noticed the sluggish behaviour when I press the gas pedal and especially when I put on the AC.

The movement is now smooth but my tachometer continues to misbehave.

I like to run a scan on it but the place is far from where I stay. Please can this be put to normal? I know something is wrong. I just want to know how bad it is.

Thank you.

Comment: Your comment of "the sluggish behaviour" indicates something is not set correctly. Is the engine fuel-injected or carburetor'ed? Is there a strong(er) smell of fuel at idle on warm-up?

Comment: @user4707 Was your implication that the tachometer did not match the actual engine RPMs, or that the tachometer was correct but the engine speed was behaving unexpectedly? Also did you ever solve the issue and do you recall what the problem was?